Can you prove the principle of induction/the well ordering principle using ZFC set theory? Or is it an axiom? If it's an axiom, why isn't it in ZFC?
I know that the principle of mathematical induction can be used to prove the well-ordering principle, and that the well-ordering principle can be used to prove the principle of mathematical induction, and as far as I understand one of them has to be an axiom. So why is it that I never see it listed as one of the axioms of ZFC set theory?
I've seen some people say that both are equivalent to the axiom choice, though I haven't been able to find a proof for that online.
I've seen others say that the axiom of infinity is what makes induction possible, but their proof assumes the fact that all natural number are transitive, which as far as I'm aware requires induction to prove.
So, is there a way to prove the principle of mathematical induction purely from the 9 axioms of ZFC set theory? Or is there some axiom that I couldn't find that makes it possible to do so, and if so what is it?
clarifications:

The principle of mathematical induction refers to: $\forall p\in\mathbb{N}\to\{T,F\}.(p(0) \wedge \forall n\in\mathbb{N}. p(n)\rightarrow p(n+1)\Rightarrow \forall n\in\mathbb{N} p(n).$
The well-ordering principle refers to: $\forall A\subseteq\mathbb{N}. \exists m\in A \forall n\in A,m\le n$. (not to be confused with the well-ordering theorem)
Something being transitive refers to: $\forall A. A\text{ is transitive} \Leftrightarrow \forall x\in A.x\subset A$.
The natural numbers refer to the ZF definition (and thus include 0): $\forall x. x\in\mathbb{N} \Leftrightarrow (\forall A. A\text{ is inductive} \rightarrow x\in A)$.


The well-ordering theorem is equivalent to the axiom of choice. Most text books will have a proof, which most likely will not involve induction. The axiom of infinity says there is an inductive set and the naturals are defined as the intersection of all inductive sets. You can use induction to prove the naturals are transitive. You don’t need the fact that the naturals are transitive to prove induction. All this stuff is in standard texts…

The axiom of choice is equivalent (over ZF) to the proposition that every set has a well-order, which has nothing to do with the fact that the standard order on the natural numbers is a well-order. How you prove this latter fact (or the principle of induction) depends on which of the many equivalent definitions of the natural numbers you are using. The definition you have written down is circular, so doesn't work without further elaboration.

Thank you for your corrections! I've updated my question to include what I understand to be the more commonly accepted definition of the naturals, though my confusion still stands.
@Porky, with regards to your comment about it being in standard texts, I don't think I have come across such texts in my search (which is admittedly limited as I don't study this material in an academic setting), can you recommend any places where I could find them?

Enderton, “Elements of set theory” is a standard one. I like “Set Theory, a first course” by Cunningham.

The axiom of regularity might be useful.

@Lucenaposition Depends on the definition used. If it’s the “minimal inductive set” definition, then well-foundedness follows from the induction principle and there’s no need to use regularity.

@Porky, thank you so much! I've found a very simple proof in "Elements of set theory" which I will post soon as an answer hear.

After looking through Elements of Set Theory I've found a very simple proof I'm satisfied with:
In ZF set theory the natruals are often defined like so:
$$\mathbb{N} = \bigcap\{ I : I\text{ is inductive} \}$$
Where an inductive set $A$ is a set that satisfies:

$\emptyset\in A$
$\forall x\in A. x\cup\{x\}\in A$

Now, look at a proposition $f\in\mathbb{N}\to\{T,F\}$ such that $f(0)$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}. f(n) \rightarrow f(n+1)$. We'll define the set $S:=\{n\in\mathbb{N} : f(n)\}$. Then:

$f(0) \rightarrow f(\emptyset) \rightarrow \emptyset\in S$
$$
   \forall n\in\mathbb{N}. f(n) \rightarrow f(n+1) \\
   \Downarrow \\
   \forall n\in\mathbb{N}. n\in S \rightarrow n+1\in S \\
   \Downarrow (A\subseteq\mathbb{N}) \\
   \forall n\in S. n+1\in S \\
   \Downarrow \\
   \forall n\in S. n\cup\{n\}\in S
   $$

So $S$ is inductive, and so $S\in\{ I : I\text{ is inductive} \}$, and so $\mathbb{N}\subseteq S$, which is equivalent to saying $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}. f(n)$.
